# Draggable FloatingActionButton in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make a draggable floating button and if possible to print the drag position in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to add a positioned widget to set the position of my button

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Offset position =Offset(20.0, 20.0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("data_repo/img/bg1.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left : position.dx,
          top  : position.dy ,
          child : Draggable(
          feedback: Container(
            child : FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {})
            ),
          child: Container(
            child : FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {}),
          ),
          childWhenDragging: Container(),
          onDragEnd: (details){
            setState(() {
              position = details.offset;
            });
            print(position);
            print(position.dx);
            print(position.dy);
            }))
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Due to the ability to compose Flutter widgets in whatever way you want to, you can simply do it like this:

```
Draggable(
    feedback: FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.drag_handle), onPressed: () {}),
    child: FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.drag_handle), onPressed: () {}),
    childWhenDragging: Container(),
    onDragEnd: (details) => print(details.offset))
```

This [`Draggable`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) can be passed as the `floatingActionButton` argument to a `Scaffold`.
The `feedback` parameter controls how the widget *that is dragged about* in the end will look like and `child` specifies how the stationary `Draggable` should look like. As you probably only want to see **one** `FloatingActionButton` *at a time*, you can pass an *empty `Container`* to `childWhenDragging`.

The `Offset` (position) of the drag will be printed to the console when releasing the drag.

Comment: just one thing ! when I release  the FloatingButton it comeback to it's first position !!! any help ?

Comment: @saidbendrioue Yes, that is the expected behavior. If you want to update its position, you will probably have to place it in a `Stack` with a `Positioned` widget and update the `position` when `onDragEnd` is called using a `StatefulWidget` and `setState`.

Comment: And if you want to control the direction of dragging, then use the `axis` field to specify horizontal or vertical line of dragging. If not specified, it's random by default

Answer (score 3):

You can use the DraggableFloatingButton package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/draggable_floating_button