# Flutter: how to create this draggable bottom widget?

Tags: flutter

I need help in creating this type of draggable bottom widget
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzpoa.jpg

Comment: It is a bottom sheet search for it. you will find more informations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draggable FloatingActionButton in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046638/draggable-floatingactionbutton-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [solid_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/solid_bottom_sheet)