# How to create always on app widget by flutter

Tags: flutter, button, widget, action

How to create a actionable floating action button that always on screen and we can move where ever we want?

[image: How to create a actionable floating action button that always on screen and we can move where ever we want?]

Comment: similar questions already exists , try asking new topics.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046638/draggable-floatingactionbutton-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Try to used [**`draggable_floating_button`**](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_floating_button) or read [this](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/66/how-to-make-floating-action-button-movable/) article

Result-> [image]

Comment: I would like to run this out side of app like assistive touch